# Appropriate request method to send tokens

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, asp.net-identity

What is the correct method to consume a resource passing a token after i am correctly authenticated? For example, is it right to do a GET with a Bearer Authorization to get an array of JSON objects or should i make a POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

> GET requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET
>   should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as
>   using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this
>   is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which
>   should not need to consider the side effects that a request should
>   cause.

and

> POST submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the
>   identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request.
>   This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of
>   existing resources or both.

So, it does not depend on passing a token. It depends whether your request just retrieves the resource or it creates/updates an existing resource.

For just retrieving a resource use GET.

For creating a new resource/updating a new resource use POST.